# upgrading Web Parts in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

what is the best approach for upgrading Web Parts in SharePoint 2010?

Is AfterDeserialize() method best approach?

pl suggest.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what upgrade means in your perspective, as most of Web parts should be upgradeable as such. 
The AfterSerialize is used still in SharePoint 2013 even, however for scenarios when you plan to add/remove additional functionality acting as a mediator for previously stored values.